# I want to set recursive object in reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux, reducers

I send get request for getting userInfo.Then i want to add this userInfo recursively .

This is my reducer

```
case types.USER_INFO_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        userInfo: action.payload,
      }
```

so every time i wan to add this userInfo recursively

Like

```
userInfo: {
 fname: '',
 lname: '',
 userInfo: {
  fname: '',
  lname: '',
  userInfo: {
   fname: '',
   lname: '',
   userInfo: {

   }
  }
 }
}
```

so every time request success i want to add object recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
case types.USER_INFO_SUCCESS:
    let current = state;
    while (current.hasOwnProperty('userInfo')) {
        current = current.userInfo;
    }
    current.userInfo = action.payload;      
    return { ...state }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i want unlimited levels of userInfo

Comment: I think you get unlimited levels with this. The loop continue until it is in the last child userInfo and then set action.payload in there.